I can't seem to accesss my main user in windows after I install ubuntu
Okay so yesterday I installed Ubuntu in my laptop, thru flashing Ubuntu 22.04 on a pendrive and then loading it, allocated 100gb to linux and booted.
At that time, I can access both windows and linux while booting. A window was coming which let me choose between linux and windows everytime I boot my laptop
And I was successfully able to log in my windows user.
Today, when I was logging in my windows user, the screen where we put in password was invisible, only the wallpaper of the lock screen was there in blurr, with power and wifi settings in bottom right.
I was not able to put in the pin.
After like 30 seconds , the windows automatically gets started with the 2nd user I have without any password which has nothing in it.
And also, wheneveer that user opens, it completely opens the desktop, then there comes a windows pop up just like a yes and no one which windows asks everytime we do something suspicious and windows asks yes or no that thing. But that was also blank, only the blurr screen shows up without any window for yes and no selection or not even anything WRITTEN.
I bypass it by doing ctrl alt del.
And then the 2nd user works fine.
I want to login my main user which has password back again and It's not happening.
Linux is working fine but I want windows tooo

Ehm that is a windows problem not linux and no a dual boot does not affect the other OS.  Only the bootloader at the start of boot is needed to pick the OS to start up after that it is solely that OS that is involved. You need to ask a site where windows users answer questions :

i get it, but still it would be great if you could suggest any help, i cant figure out anythign mann
